# Laravel 5.4 to 5.5 upgrade - "Class login does not exist" (Reflection error)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I have searched all of my code and I can find nowhere that I am calling a class called "login" - neither lower case nor camel. I have no models called login. I have followed the 5.4 to 5.5 upgrade notes. Any ideas? The line appears to be Container.php 752.

Comment: Please include exact error and show packages you have installed. It's possible that there is problem with one of packages

Comment: please post your composer.php and an image of what you are getting as error msg.

Comment: Thanks very much for replying. In fact I have found it. So that people might be aware, I had a middleware group 'login' which did not exist. Strangely in 5.4 that causes no error but in 5.5 it squawks!